# How do I add ActiveRecord to a rails app initialized without ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I created a rails app with the -O option (i.e. without ActiveRecord). But now I want to add active record to it. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Inside of `config/application.rb` you should see where the `ActiveRecord` railtie is commented out (see below).

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Uncomment it.

Also make sure to add a `database.yml` file and the a database adapter gem (e.g. `sqlite3`) to your Gemfile.